# What is the meaning of these label in top?

Tags: top

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm

```
top - 17:05:46 up 7 min,  1 user,  load average: 227.48, 89.29, 36.78
Tasks: 1758 total,  25 running, 1555 sleeping,   1 stopped, 177 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.5%us, 32.1%sy, 58.0%ni,  4.7%id,  2.7%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.8%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65951776k total, 20235624k used, 45716152k free, 10882480k buffers
Swap:  4194300k total,        0k used,  4194300k free,  3291164k cached
```

What's the meaning of that?

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm doesn't say anything about that?

us means usage. sy seems to be system. ni? What is ni? What is id? What is wa? what is si? Why so much cpu time is spent on ni and sy?

Comment: Maybe this could help - https://linuxaria.com/howto/understanding-the-top-command-on-linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux "top" command: What are us, sy, ni, id, wa, hi, si and st (for CPU usage)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18918/linux-top-command-what-are-us-sy-ni-id-wa-hi-si-and-st-for-cpu-usage)

Answer (score 7):

From `man top`:

```
   us, user    : time running un-niced user processes
   sy, system  : time running kernel processes
   ni, nice    : time running niced user processes
   wa, IO-wait : time waiting for I/O completion
   hi : time spent servicing hardware interrupts
   si : time spent servicing software interrupts
   st : time stolen from this vm by the hypervisor
```

It doesn't say anything about what `id` means, but I would presume that it stands for "idle," since it's always at about ~85% for my system and adding up all the numbers results in 100%.