# Linux “top” command: What are "be" and "un" (for CPU usage)?

Tags: top

This question complements [Linux "top" command: What are us, sy, ni, id, wa, hi, si and st (for CPU usage)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18918/linux-top-command-what-are-us-sy-ni-id-wa-hi-si-and-st-for-cpu-usage).

In Ubuntu Xenial the `top` gives e.g.:

> %CPU(s):  0,6 be,  0,1 sy,  1,5 ni, 97,6 un,  0,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st

The man-pages don't explain `be` and `un`. I guess `un` must be the well-known `us` ("un-niced user processes") and `be` the former `id` ("idle operations"), although the percentages make it likely to be the other way round.

Comment: What language is your `top` using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your numbers use , and not . I think your output is localized (i.e. translated):

```
%CPU(s): 0,6 be, 0,1 sy, 1,5 ni, 97,6 un, 0,1 wa, 0,0 hi, 0,0 si, 0,0 st
```

Fits perfectly with:

```
%CPU(s): 0.6 us, 0.1 sy, 1.5 ni, 97.6 id, 0.1 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
```

So my guess is that 'user' starts with 'be' in your language (benutzer?), and 'idle' starts with 'un' (unbeschäftigt?). If you are based in Köln this seems plausible.

Comment: Indeed! Couldn't make the connection. Would be could to have commands and their respective man pages in language sync.

Comment: @dr0i Yes, if the man page is translated but describes the English versions of the two-character shorthands while the command actually uses translated versions, that would be worth filing an internationalization bug report.

Comment: The man page is in English, thus it correctly explains the two-character shorthands in English, while the command is in German. I should always stick to English commands I guess.